# Order by IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to order by column if it actually exists?

ie: `SELECT * ORDER BY IF(EXISTS(order_column), order_column ASC, name_column DESC)`

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean: Do you want to check if the table column exists, or if it contains values? Usually `EXISTS` is used in combination with sub-queries in order to check if the sub-query returns any records. If you want to check if the actual column exists, you can do that with `SHOW COLUMNS`.

Comment: and please explain what you mean by "if it exists", if I take the literal meaning, if the column doesn't exist, the query won't run but will produce an error. If you mean "if the value in the column isn't null", then please edit your question to say that.

Comment: I want to check if it actually exists. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: That answer doesn't help. Are you saying there is sometimes a value in that column and sometimes not?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ISNULL Instead

```
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(order_column, name_column)
```

Not sure how you'd add the DESC or ASC tho...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my untested guess:

```
ORDER BY IF(ISNULL(order_column), "", order_column) ASC, name_column DESC
```

If order_column is NULL, an empty string will be substituted, which won't affect the sort. If it's not NULL, it will be sorted before the name column.

If Mysql won't let you use an expression in the ORDER BY, you can always create an "artificial" column in the SELECT:

```
SELECT 
  IF (ISNULL(order_column), "     ", order_column) 
     AS my_order_column, 
  name_column 
FROM table 
ORDER BY my_order_column ASC, name_column DESC.
```

Comment: I've came up with something similar myself, but since i need to sort by order_column only if it actually exists, this won't work...

Comment: One of us is badly misunderstanding. Can you give us an example of some possible data and the result you'd expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

No, EXISTS must only be used with a subquery and in the WHERE clause. May you be more specific? What do you mean by 'existing column'?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is create an expression that evaluate the if exists as part of the select query. You can have the expression return order_column or name_column

implemention depends on the SQL you are using, but here you can normallly us IIf(...) but you may need to check for null